# How to transform an indexed array into an associative array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, iteration, associative-array

Is there a way to transform the following array of objects:

```
   array =  [
        { date: "08/18", id: 1 },
        { date: "08/14", id: 2 },
        { date: "08/15", id: 3 }
    ]
```

Into this? Only returning the dates:

```
array2 = ["08/18", "08/14", "08/15"]
```

I've been trying to push the date elements as it follows, but it doesn's seem to work:

```
array.map(e => {
    array2.push(e.date)
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `array.map(({date})=>date);`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the array `map` function:

```
array2 = array.map(object => object.date);
```